# PasscodeScreen not changing route on validation

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, when the app launches, a passcode screen appears. When the passcode is validated, I want the screen to change to my home screen. This is the code I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homescreen.dart';
import 'package:passcode_screen/passcode_screen.dart';

class EnterPasscode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return EnterPasscodeState();
  }
}

class EnterPasscodeState extends State<EnterPasscode> {
  final StreamController<bool> _verificationNotifier =
      StreamController<bool>.broadcast();
  List<String> digits = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: PasscodeScreen(
        title: Text(
          'Enter App Passcode',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),
        ),
        circleUIConfig: CircleUIConfig(),
        keyboardUIConfig: KeyboardUIConfig(),
        passwordEnteredCallback: _onPasscodeEntered,
        cancelButton: Text(
          '',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
          semanticsLabel: 'Delete',
        ),
        deleteButton: Text(
          'Delete',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
          semanticsLabel: 'Delete',
        ),
        shouldTriggerVerification: _verificationNotifier.stream,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        // cancelCallback: _onPasscodeCancelled,
        digits: digits,
        passwordDigits: 6,
      ),
    );
  }

  _onPasscodeEntered(String enteredPasscode) {
    bool isValid = "123456" == enteredPasscode;
    _verificationNotifier.add(isValid);
    if (isValid) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _verificationNotifier.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

But it doesn't push the HomeScreen(). Instead, the app pauses and this screen appears:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi! Is there any error message?

Comment: No, there is no error message. The app just pauses and the screen shown in the image appears. (I'm using VSCode as the editor)

Comment: It seems that pushReplacement doesn't work when you has only one root screen. I can't explain that correctly, but  can suggest you to use FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder to handle pass entering result to replace the root screen. Code will be in answers

Comment: Ok, can you suggest the code please?

Comment: Sure, i've done

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StreamBuilder` to achieve this:

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  final _passCodePassedStreamController = StreamController<bool>()..add(false);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passCodePassedStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        ...
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _passCodePassedStreamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final passCodePassed = snapshot.data;
              return passCodePassed
                  ? HomePage()
                  : EnterPasscode(passed: () {
                      _passCodePassedStreamController.add(true);
                    });
            }));
  }
}

class EnterPasscode extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function passed;

  const EnterPasscode({Key key, @required this.passed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build method implementation.
    // Here you should call `passed()` when right password entered
  }
}
```

Comment: It is now giving me this error:

`The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<bool>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<bool, AsyncSnapshot<bool>>#25ee9):
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`

Followed by:
`The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<bool>`

Comment: Did you create stream controller exactly like this: `StreamController<bool>()..add(false)`?

Comment: If it is so, try to add `initialData: false` to StreamBuilder parameters

Comment: yes, I put `StreamController<bool>()..add(false)` exactly like that

Comment: Ok so the StreamBuilder error got solved, but the original issue i.e the app pausing and the screen shown in the image is still there

Comment: it's really strange, because I just run my code and all is ok. Please provide full code of your App class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228568/discussion-between-mol0ko-and-rishic).